# Blumenthal 0-1 law

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $(B_t)$ be a Brownian motion. Consider the event : $B(n)>a \sqrt n $occuring infinitely often.

I want to prove that this event has probability 1.
we can see that, by rescaling property, $$\mathbb{P}(B(n)>a\sqrt{n} \mbox{ occurs infinitely often})\geq \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}(B(n)>a\sqrt{n})=P(B(1)>a)>0$$

Now I want to see that this is a 0-1 event to conclude using Blumenthal 0-1 law

Comment: I don't agree with yr first inequality, although I do agree that brownian scaling is the easy way to do this.

Comment: the first inequality is just an application of Fatou's lemma

Comment: By time inversion, this has the same probability as the event  that $B(1/n) > a/\sqrt{n}$ infinitely often.  This is clearly in $\mathcal{F}_{0+}$.

Comment: you're right, (see above comment). I had this argument in mind: look in at $n=2^j$, then you can show that there is a prob bounded away from zero of etc. (compare to geometric) , and omit 0-1 law.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: use the first Borel-Cantelli lemma

I feel sorry about the above hint, as I thought this is a typical question using B-C lemma, but actually it does not work here.

You are on the right track, and it remains to be shown this is an tail event, which is not difficult. In fact, this is the Theorem 8.2.8 in Durrett's book-- *Probability: Theory and Examples* (4th edition).

Comment: I don't see how that's useful here.

Comment: To use that lemma, first I need to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(E_n)<\infty$ where $E_n= B(n)<a\sqrt{n}$ but I don't see how

Comment: @user112978 Sorry about this, for $B-C$ lemma $1$ cannot be applied here, and $B-C$ lemma $2$ requires independence.